# Proving probability of intersection greater than or equal to probabilities of events - N + 1

Tags: probability

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:

$$P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_N) \geq  1 - N + \sum_{j=1}^{N} P(A_j)$$

I couldn't really figure out the analytical proof so I thought about it as a game where the RHS is trying to beat the LHS under certain conditions. I was wondering if someone could help with an analytical solution.

I basically said there are two cases.

Case 1 is when $P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_N) = 0$. In this case, the RHS knows $\sum_{j=1}^{N} P(A_j) = P(A_1 \cup .... \cup A_N)$ because they are disjoint, and so RHS will try to maximize by making $P(A_1 \cup .... \cup A_N) = 1$. In this case, though, we get $0 \geq 1 - N + 1$, where if $N > 1$ (otherwise LHS wouldn't be 0), the best RHS can do is 0, which makes $0 \geq 0$.

Case 2 is when $P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_N) \neq 0$. In this case, RHS can maximize their side by making every $P(A_j) = 1$. In this case, though, we get $1 \geq 1$. Now, RHS will take a new approach where they make every $P(A_j) = 1$ except make one of them smaller, so that LHS is reduced. Still we just get $p \geq p$, where $p$ is the probability of the event that RHS chooses to vary.

I think we need to solve this using the fact that if $\sum_{j=1}^{N} P(A_j)$ will have intersections when $> 1$, but honestly not sure.

Comment: In regards to your attempts... they are both wrong (i.e., they aren't proving anything, except maybe one special case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
P \left( \bigcap_{j = 1}^N A_j \right) &= 1 - P \left( \bigcup_{j = 1}^N A_j^\complement \right) \geq 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^N P\left( A_j^\complement \right) \\
&= 1 - \left( \sum_{j = 1}^N \big( 1 - P(A_j) \big) \right) = 1 - N + \sum_{j = 1}^N P(A_j).
\end{align*}
$$